# Remove "/us/" from the default iOS App Store link?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

The default link I got for my iOS app from iTunes Connect looks like this:

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/name/id1234566789?ls=1&mt=8

Does the `/us/` part mean that link will always show the US AppStore or will it automatically redirect to the AppStore of the users country? Should I remove that part from the link?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

This will bring up the US store every time, ignoring the user's location.

What you can do is to delete *us/*. That will always show the app store with user-location-based region.

Hope that helps :)